# Entity Translation Im/Export with image field

Tags: i18n-l10n, importing-exporting

I have an CSV with lots of Nodes that I imported via Feeds Module. The fields contain a title, a textfield and an image. I'm using Entity Translation. Now I want to export and import those fields to add an english translation. I can export the textfields but not the image field, they just don't appear in the UI. Is there a solution how I can import the englisch version of my image field?

Comment: Isn't the image language neutral? That would explain why it is not showing up in the export. There is no need for translating an image path...

Comment: No, I marked the image field as translateable.